# Is there a shortcut to close the build system area in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext2

I'm familiar with the CTRL+B shortcut to run the build system within Sublime Text 2, but is there a shortcut for getting rid of it?

Comment: **Derp**, should I just delete this ya think?

Comment: Haha I have no idea. I felt it embarrassing to post as an answer. That is why I commented. Btw, you could perhaps use chat.stackoverflow.com next time for things like these :)

Comment: Thanks, I'll probably leave it unless I hear a differing opinion. Maybe I'll look back on this and remember the nature of being a noob. It'll be worth a chuckle I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

With the build system selected, it's the escape key. I'll excuse myself now.